# I have installed git from homebrew, and instead of installing it in /usr/local/bin it's in /opt/homebrew/bin/git, how can I move it?

Tags: homebrew, path, git

I've changed my $PATH variable to `/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (previously `/usr/local/bin` wasn't at the begging) and tried to reinstall through homebrew with no results.

Also, I currently have this two versions of git:

```
git is `/opt/homebrew/bin/git` (2.33.0)

git is `/usr/bin/git.`         (2.30.1 (Apple Git-130))
```

If I am correct, the `/usr/bin/git` version is the native one.

Is anyone able to help me or should I resign myself to having git there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think you need to break what Homebrew has installed?  Since you have `/opt/homebrew`, that means you have an M1-based machine.  Homebrew installs in different prefix depending on which processor architecture you are using.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I thought I had broken it, and if git was there I there might be problems down the road, but it turns out I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: roger, Welcome to AskDifferent.  I have rolled back to the original question removing "SOLVED: It turns out it installed correctly given that I’m using an M1  machine. " as that is not how things are done here.  If you like to self-answer your question, posting that as an answer, you certainly can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

> This script installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (`/usr/local` for macOS Intel, `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux) ...

So assuming you have an M1 Mac it‘s installed where it is supposed to be.